# Using vector images to scale for app platforms

Tags: android, mobile, vector, titanium

Images in apps come in many shapes or sizes, but to save space and editing time is there a way to use scaleable vector images?

Ideally I would have one vector image at middle resolution, I could then detect the screen size and scale the vector how I need and add the background using some custom gradients.

I'm using titanium for this.

Answer (score 2):

Titanium doesn't yet support vector graphics, though it is available in native Android code via [Shape Drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape). There is a third-party [SVG library](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/) available for Android SDK.

For Titanium, branch the code based on the device screen size ([Titanium.Platform.DisplayCaps](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.1/Titanium.Platform.DisplayCaps)), and find an image that works with decent performance on the device.

You can use PNGs with transparency and apply a background color to your view object.

Comment: Thanks, I think PNG is the way forward. Do you know if there is a way to avoid the need for an image for different screen sizes? Android with no gradient background sucks but never mind

Comment: The alternative is to scale the graphics to fit. If you were developing with the Android SDK, you could use the Nine Patch Drawable, which allows you to scale images in a much better way. You could use composite (multiple images combined into one) images to duplicate the functionality.

Comment: Does titanium support vector graphics yet? It's 2017.

Answer (score 1):

I've found away round making different sized drawable:

Basically just one have folder called drawable within the res folder.
Make your artwork in what ever you use but make it large (at least 1080p for future devices).

Save the image's as PNG within the drawable folder but save them large. (IE at least 1000x1000)

Write a function that loads in the PNG but scales it (according to screen size & percentage of what size you want the drawable to be. So 20% of 800px width is 120px). I've managed to do this bit with 30ish lines of code, can't paste my code since I'm not on my working machine.

For me this has worked across all my apps for all devices, I've not had a single crash yet (1000's of installs, including Live Wallpapers).